# Prevent Redirect To Cart Page After Clicking Add To Cart - 3rd Party Shopify Theme

Tags: html, shopify

When the add to cart button in hit, it takes you straight to the cart, which doesnt give shoppers an opportunity to shop around.

How can I change it so that the page remains the same, so clients can continue shopping?

I don’t have much experience in web development, but have attached the product-template.liquid, if that helps.

Thank you all!

```
  {% endif %}
    {% if settings.upsell_popup_enable and upsell_enable %}
      $('.AddToCart').click(function(){
        var flag_addcart = true;
        $('.product_properties').each(function(){
          var val = $(this).find('input').val();
          var val_charlimit = $(this).find('input').data('charlimit');
          if(val == "") {
            flag_addcart = false;
            $(this).find('input').addClass("ui-state-error");
          } else {
            $(this).find('input').removeClass("ui-state-error");
            $(this).find('.error-limit').hide();
            if(val_charlimit != undefined) {
              if(val.length > val_charlimit){
                flag_addcart = false;
                $(this).find('input').addClass("ui-state-error");
                $(this).find('.error-limit').html("Oops, we won't have space to print all that, try something shorter.").show();
              }
            }
          }
        });
        if(flag_addcart) {
          if($(window).width() > 540){
            var width = "500px";
          } else {
            var width = "90%";  
          }
          $('#upsell-popup').find('.modal-content').css('width', width);
          $('#upsell-popup').addClass("in");
        }
        return false;
      });
      $('#upsell-popup .close-upsell').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#upsell-popup').removeClass("in");
      });
      $('#upsell-popup .upsell-yes-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#upsell-popup').removeClass("in");
        $("#Quantity").val({{ settings.quantity_upsell }});
        var product_free_id = "";
        {% for variant in all_products[settings.free_product].variants %}
          {% if variant == all_products[settings.free_product].selected_or_first_available_variant %}
            product_free_id = {{variant.id}};
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        if(product_free_id !== "") {
          var data = 'id='+ product_free_id + '&quantity=1';
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(res){
              setTimeout(function(){
                $("#AddToCartForm--{{ product.id }}").submit();
              }, 1000);
            }
          });
        } else {
          $("#AddToCartForm--{{ product.id }}").submit();
        }
        
      });
      $('#upsell-popup .upsell-no-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#upsell-popup').removeClass("in");
        $("#AddToCartForm--{{ product.id }}").submit();
      });
    {% endif %}
    {% for collection in product.collections limit: 1 %}
      timber.recordLastCollection({
        collection: "{{ collection.handle }}"
      });
    {% endfor %}
  });
</script>
{% if settings.show_related_products %}
<hr class="releted--products-hr" />
```

Comment: Many themes have a theme setting that you can toggle that controls the add-to-cart behaviour, usually under either a "Product" or "Cart" related heading. Have you confirmed that your theme does not have anything built-in that can be turned on that way?

Comment: If not, the stay-on-page style add-to-cart is managed by Javascript running on your site. If you're not comfortable writing your own javascript features for your store, I would recommend trying out a few other themes to find one that has the stay-on-page feature you're looking for. (At this time, most themes - even the free ones - have this as a feature).  You can see the free themes on the theme store, and clicking through lets you see a demo where you can test for features you want: https://themes.shopify.com/themes?sort_by=most_recent&price%5B%5D=free

Answer (score 1):

Yes, be cautious and always make a duplicate of your current theme. Furthermore, you need to prevent the link from redirecting you to the cart page by adding event.preventDefault() in the function block. Refer to this for a better explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

```js
//Before 
$('.AddToCart').click(function(){
 ...
 }
// After
$('.AddToCart').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 ...
}
```

Make sure you add e.preventDefault() before all the other code.